# I don't understand how this line of code works

Tags: python

```
list =  [x*x for x in range(5)]

def fun(L):
    del L[L[2]]
    return L

print(fun(list))
```

Hello, I need help understanding this line of code: **del L[L[2]]**. I understand how just del L[2] would result in an answer of *0, 1, 9, 16* (deleting the 2nd positioned list-item), however I'm not sure how, in the actual answer of *0, 1, 4, 9,* the 16 gets deleted. That first 'L' is what I'd like to understand. Is it multiplying the list index by 2 and deleting the 4th item? If so, how does that work? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: `L[2]` is 4. So `L[L[2]]` is `L[4]`. So `del L[L[2]]` is `del L[4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list `L` looks like `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]`. `L[2]` is `4`. So basically, you are deleting `L[L[2]]` or `L[4]` which is `16`.

PS : It's not a good practice to use keywords as variable names. Here, `list` is not a good variable name.